# Jquery Mobile Logon Loop

Tags: jquery-mobile

Knocked-out a simple jQuery Mobile site  with [logon -> index -> content] pages.

If I use the back button to the logon page, I can't escape no matter what I do - forward, back, filling it in, nothing.

I'd like to remove the `#logon` page from the navigation, so you cannot get back to it without typing it in, or logging out - any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing the ajax navigation full stop and sticking to manual, not as pretty but headaches avoided!

Comment: AND it has the added benefit of working if you have a device that has JavaScript disabled, right?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to keep a page from showing up in history (with jquery mobile) is show that page in a dialog.  This model works particularly well in situations where the content that would be in a dialog is either tangential to the main content or some sort of interrupt (which the login process is).  [See an example here](http://jsfiddle.net/sgliser/8nf3x/2/). *DISLAIMER: this is not the right way to implement content like this in the long run, it is only meant to show the effect of using a dialog in a login process to bypass insertion into history.*

Another (more manual) route would be to use the a normal jqm page and do your login by way of an ajax posting.  If the response came back as successful, then use location.replace() to remove the the current (logon) page from history.